# Angular mat date picker is not working properly

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

[Angular mat datepicker style is breaking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2mrD.png)

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NumberAcceptModule,
    SelectDropDownModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      timeOut: 5000,
      easing: "ease-in",
      positionClass: "toast-top-right",
      preventDuplicates: true,
      closeButton: true,
      progressBar: true,
    }),
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers: [clearState] }),
    !environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument() : [],
    StoreModule.forFeature(customerFeatureKey, customerReducer),
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, {
      passThruUnknownUrl: true,
    }),
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: { appearance: "fill" },
    },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: RequestInterceptor, multi: true },
    AuthGaurd,
    EncrDecrService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Completely disabled</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp1">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dp1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mucxR.png)

Comment: share your code after that  any one can help

Comment: It looks like you are missing the styles. How did you setup your theming? Are you using a prebuilt theme or a custom theme? Please have a look into the [getting started guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) and [theming guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming).

Comment: Got it. I missed out style import in style.scss file. `@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';`. Now it's working fine. Thanks @Vasim Hayat